# How to render a pdf file with all of its images and styles in a view with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, itext

I am using iTextSharp 5.5.5.0 and I want to read a pdf file and render it to html with all of its styles and images. I have tried the following but it returns a pure text:

```
public string Index()
{
    fileName = Server.MapPath("~/1.pdf");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            currentText = String.Join(string.Empty, currentText.Reverse());
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: iText does not contain a PDF renderer, and creating such a renderer is quite a complex task.

Comment: @mkl So, could you please look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657014/how-to-convet-pdf-pages-to-image-by-itextsharp-in-c